# Jquery still doesn't run when page created by php script

Tags: php, jquery

I find the Jquery script I have refuses to run when the page has been generated by my php script.
I would appreciate a different pair of eyes to look over my code please.

```
<?php
.
. DB log in and verification done here
.
.
<html><head><link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>body { background-image: url(../riders/'.$riderno.'/rider_picture.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;top: 10%;background-position: center;}
</style><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    $(".session").click(function () {
        var src = $(this).data("href");
        var title = $(this).data("id");
        alert("Clicked - " + src);
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
                 .html("<iframe style="border: 1px; " src="'+ src + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>")
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 625,
                    width: $(window).width() - 20,
                    height: $(window).height() - 20,
                    title: title
                });
                $dialog.dialog("open");
        });
    });
    </script></head>
<body><div class="RiderInfo">
<?php


echo "<div class='Week'>";
$total_duration = date("H:i:s", strtotime("0:0:0"));
$total_distance = 0;
$total_tss = 0;
$total_hrtss = 0;
$avg_if = 0;
$avg_hrif = 0;
$sessions = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `RiderLog` WHERE `RiderNo` = $riderno AND `RideDate` >= '$startdate' AND `RideDate` < '$enddate'  ORDER by RideDate ASC"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$record=0;
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $thisdate = $startdate;
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    do {
        echo "<div class='date'><div class='day'><strong>".date("D", strtotime($thisdate))."</strong></div>";
        while ($thisdate == date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['RideDate']))) {
            $sessions++;
            ?><button data-id='#dialog<?php echo $record?>' class='session' data-href='fitanalysis.php?rider=<?php echo $riderno ?>&file=<?php echo $row['FIT_file']?>'><div class='duration'><?php echo $row['Duration']?></div><div class='distance'><?php echo $row['Distance'] ?>km</div>
<?php            $total_duration = date("H:i:s",strtotime($total_duration)+(strtotime($row['Duration'])-strtotime("00:00:00")));
            $total_distance += $row['Distance'];
?></button><?php
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $record++;
        }
        $thisdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($thisdate.'+ 1 day'));
        echo "</div>";
    } while ($thisdate <= $enddate);
    echo "<div class='WeekSummary'><strong>Week Summary</strong><br>Duration : ".date("H:i:s", strtotime($total_duration))."<br>Distance : $total_distance km<br>TSS : $total_tss<br>Average IF : ".$avg_if/$sessions."</div>";
    echo "</form>";
} else {

clear up and finish html page.
```

Comment: Please, prepare a minimal working example, that will allow us to reproduce your problem. We can't run your script as we don't have your database. Post only minimal HTML and javascript, that don't work here.

Comment: Well, this is completely different that what we looked at before. But your troubles are coming from how you punch in and out of PHP & HTML. For example `'.$riderno.'` should have been  `<?php echo $riderno; ?>`

Comment: ' . $variable . ' only works if you are in a string. Remember the last post you made, I showed you how to not wrap EVERYTHING in a string?

Comment: Your PHP code is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks @Madness. It's the more complicated script I'm trying to get working. In essence should all 'echo' entries be converted to <?php ...; ?> ?

Comment: Well if you didnt have syntax errors in your javascript, it might run better `"<iframe style="`, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a few thing first of all, this probably isn't going to work out well for you.  You should replace that leading double quote with a single one.

```
.html("<iframe style="border: 1px; " src="'+
```

Secondly, this really just irritates me

```
var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
```

is this javascript or PHP?  Using the `$` for javascript variables is unnecessary and just makes the code harder to read.

Whats all this at the top a

```
<?php
.
. DB log in and verification done here
.
.
<html><head><link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>body { background-image: url(../riders/'.$riderno.'/rider_picture.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;top: 10%;background-position: center;}
</style><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then latter you have

```
 <?php
```

but never close the first one?  Kind of a mess going on there.

Comment: A lot of programmers use $ to preface variables that are jQuery objects like `var $testDiv =  $('#testDiv'); `  then later calling `$testDiv.html(someHtml);`

Comment: Well to be honest I'm surprised you don't get just a white screen.

Comment: Im not the OP, your other points are all quite valid :)

Comment: Sorry, I quit paying attention when I saw the opening php tag.

Comment: I had a weird issue with use of the $1 as a variable in javascript and preg_replace one time, took about 2 days to figure out.  So, I tend to be a bit picky on code conventions.

Comment: Thank you for all useful contributions, issue is now resolved for me, getting to grips with this new jquery thing. I've got much to learn about posting on here, esp regarding DB code. Issue was the leading double quote.